# Swift Mailer dont't send to "to" but to bcc

Tags: php, swiftmailer, bcc

I am working on a Mailing-List system combined with an online Forum.
Mail Input (Via Postfix forward to Script) works and after receiving an E-Mail the script should process it and send it out.

Processing and everything works, sending too.

I Have a list (list@example.com) that is accessible for few adresses (eg user1@ user2@ user3@example.com and user1@ user2@ user3@otherdomain.com)

If one user sends a mail to the list it is delivered t oa php script, that does the processing (Checking if user has rights, adding some Information to the Message eg. sign out link) and sends the mail out to the list-recipients.

But I want to have a behaviour like this for the from the script Outgoing mail:

- From is original Sender
- To in the mail is the Mailing list (list@example.com)[X]
- Reply To is the mailing list
- Subject is Modified
- Body is modified
- Real To is the receiver of the list.

**Here's the problem:** 
[X] So I want to send out a Mail, that just delivers to bcc and not to to, but has a to address.

I am Using swift-mailer in Codeigniter.

If I'll send it to the list itself, I would create a infinite loop, because all mails to the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `To` field indicates a recipient. To not have a `To` recipient, leave the `To` field empty.

In order to workaround this and include a `To` field that will *not* be a recipient, I believe some lists use a `X-BeenThere` header:

```
X-BeenThere: listaddress@domain.org
To: listaddress@domain.org
```

Then when the list receives the email back — which it will do along with all your BCC "real" recipients — it can simply ignore it because `X-BeenThere` matches its address. This prevents the loop.

I do not know how standard this is, whether Swift-Mailer supports it and if not how to make it so. I observed this precedent with the [gpsd-users](http://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/gpsd-users) list.

Comment: So you mean, I should send the mail to the List and set an additional header and when my list handler sees that header, it ignores the mail? In that Case I have a complexity of 2n instead of n, beause every e-mail has to be parsed n+1 times. (The real mail + every fake mails with X-BeenThere. Would be a acceptable solution if I find no other one. Thanks!

Comment: @keykiller91: That's what I mean yes. And `n+1` does not lead to a complexity of `O(2n)` at all. It is still `O(n)` (since we ignore both coefficients and lower-order constants). If one extra email dispatch is your bottleneck then I suggest you have some serious underlying problems that should be solved first.

Comment: ah... you mean not per recipient. you mean send more than one bcc at once ;-) Ok. got it. had a terrible weekend.

Comment: @keykiller91: Oh, that's a given! But even if that weren't the case, adding one more recipient would not suddenly change the complexity of the solution.